# How to setup routes in Rouille by iterating a vector of routes

Tags: rust

The [Rouille hello world example](https://github.com/tomaka/rouille/blob/master/examples/hello-world.rs) shows how to use the `router!` macro for a fixed set of routes.

The following example code illustrates the need to be able to "bootstrap" routes from a database or from pluggable code - which I've currently been able to do with the Iron web framework:

```
pub struct Route {
    pub http_method: String,
    pub url_path: String,
    pub callback_func: fn(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response>,
}

impl Route {
    pub fn new(m: String, u: String, f: fn(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response>) -> Route {
        Route {
            http_method: m,
            url_path: u,
            callback_func: f,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // router is an Iron middleware
    let mut router = Router::new();

    // prepare routes for bootstrapping into the Iron router
    let r1 = Route::new("get".to_string(), "/*".to_string(), my_callback_func);
    let r2 = Route::new("get".to_string(), "/".to_string(), my_callback_func);

    let mut routes = Vec::new();
    routes.push(r1);
    routes.push(r2);

    for route in routes.iter_mut() {
        if route.http_method == "get" {
            // passes each route to the Iron router
            router.get(&route.url_path, (&*route).callback_func);
        } // else if, put, post, delete...
    }

    Iron::new(router).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
}

fn my_callback_func(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    //...
}
```

[(Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=526cd1a0d0cd0307a51cd68a6972d70b&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Although I'm reading up on macros in Rust, I do not have a good enough understanding of [Rouille's `router!` macro](https://github.com/tomaka/rouille/blob/master/src/router.rs), Rust or macros in general, to figure out how to achieve the equivalent with Rouille.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: you want to migrate from Iron to Rouille. In addition you would like to read from a database (so you don't have your routes hard coded in the executable) and you would like to use Rouille's `router!` macro but you don't see how you could achieve that with data coming out of a db. Now: why don't you just register the routing function and *not* use the `router!` macro? E.g. in [this example}(https://github.com/tomaka/rouille/blob/9afdd2d42acf4ffdd3d70c8c5902d83fa8213d3f/examples/login-session.rs#L60) in the `handle_route` fn use a db instead of a hard wired code?

Comment: I don't quite follow you. The handle_route function uses  both the router! macro and still also with hardcoded routes within.

Comment: I think I could come up with a rough example of what I mean - but before I craft that: what is your use case? Is it some sort of CMS? There is [this example](https://github.com/tomaka/rouille/blob/9afdd2d42acf4ffdd3d70c8c5902d83fa8213d3f/examples/database.rs) in rouille which explains how to interact with DBs but it is "only" for CRUD requests for urls like `/note/123`

Comment: you've put quite a lot of emphasis on the word "database". It's not so much about that. It's about not always hardcoding your routes - you might save them in a configuration db, or a global collection (vector etc like in my simplified example) which pluggable code would then be able to push new routes into. It's about flexibility instead of hardcoded routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine [the main source of the `router` macro](https://github.com/tomaka/rouille/blob/93a8a410cbdb5f434b97783d39f9d228bf0ee7b7/src/router.rs#L74-L99), it's long-ish but not supremely complicated:

```
($request:expr, $(($method:ident) ($($pat:tt)+) => $value:block,)* _ => $def:expr) => {
    {
        let request = &$request;

        // ignoring the GET parameters (everything after `?`)
        let request_url = request.url();
        let request_url = {
            let pos = request_url.find('?').unwrap_or(request_url.len());
            &request_url[..pos]
        };

        let mut ret = None;

        $({
            if ret.is_none() && request.method() == stringify!($method) {
                ret = router!(__check_pattern request_url $value $($pat)+);
            }
        })+

        if let Some(ret) = ret {
            ret
        } else {
            $def
        }
    }
};
```

In words, it takes a request, zero-or-more patterns to match, and a default. It gets ahold of the URL, then dispatches to the other arms of the macro to see if the URL matches the path and does some recursive trickery to define some variables with components of the path. Whichever arm matches first will set the return value, and if nothing matches, the default will be used.

Unfortunately, the macro expects `ident`s for the methods and the paths, so basically you cannot use it with expressions. This means we can't pass in variables or literals like `"foo"`. This makes it very difficult for you.

So, we do what all good programmers do: copy and paste the code. Lifting chunks out of the macro and repurpose them:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rouille;

use rouille::Request;
use rouille::Response;

struct Route(&'static str, &'static str, fn(&Request) -> Response);

fn main() {
    let routes = [
        Route("GET", "/one", do_one),
        Route("GET", "/two", do_two),
    ];

    rouille::start_server("0.0.0.0:9080", move |request| {
        let mut result = None;

        let request = &request;

        // ignoring the GET parameters (everything after `?`)
        let request_url = request.url();
        let request_url = {
            let pos = request_url.find('?').unwrap_or(request_url.len());
            &request_url[..pos]
        };

        for &Route(method, path, f) in &routes {
            if result.is_none() {
                // This checking of the path is terrible, limited, and hacky
                if request.method() == method && request_url.ends_with(path) {
                    result = Some(f(request));
                }
            }
        }

        result.unwrap_or_else(|| Response::text("Default!"))
    });
}

fn do_one(_: &Request) -> Response {
    Response::text("hello world one")
}

fn do_two(_: &Request) -> Response {
    Response::text("hello world two")
}
```

This runs the various handlers for `/one`, `/two` and everything else.

---

I'm no expert in Rouille, in fact I've never used it before today, but it certainly seems like you are trying to use it for something beyond what it is currently designed for. Perhaps this is deliberate and the authors are attempting to present a very opinionated tool. Perhaps it is accidental and they haven't thought of this use case. Perhaps it is temporary, and they just haven't gotten around to it.

Either way, I'd suggest asking the authors. If it's not an intended use-case, they can update the project docs to clearly state so. Otherwise they might create issues to implement the feature, and you could be instrumental in helping design it.

Comment: It's like I feared then. Thanks for the explanation and example anyway. By the way, would you happen to know what the following means: "The pattern of the URL and the closure must be inside parentheses. This is to bypass limitations of Rust's macros system.". It is mentioned here: https://docs.rs/rouille/1.0.0/rouille/macro.router.html

Comment: @Dac0d3r it's hard to tell exactly. Usually something like that comes about because macros still have to adhere to Rust's grammar. Generally, this restricts what types of tokens can follow other types of tokens. In certain cases, it's impossible to determine if two tokens should be treated as one, so you have to add disambiguating markers.

Comment: Thanks - makes perfect sense now :-)